# What distribution is this borne out by real data?

Tags: probability-distributions

Hi I am looking at submission data - the length of time it takes for someone to complete a flow which involves submitting an item of content.

I am getting the following distributions.

Two quick questions:

- What best describes the frequency distribution? I am thinking lognormal but not sure
- Is the mean the best statistic to use e.g. 'mean submission time is hh:mm'? Is there a better e.g. median or % of submissions below hh:mm?

Thanks in advance.

[image: distribution of submission times]